# ListView is getting populated with same values for entire size of List

Tags: android, listview

```
/*
this is the class which is called when a button is pressed in main activity. onResume is called along with onCreate first, and the list is getting populated with the last row input from the database multiple times.
```

the aim is to populate listview with data from the table in database.
when is onResume called?
    */

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Expenses extends Activity {
    ListView l;Databasehelper mydb;List<ListViewItem> items;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expenses);
        l= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        mydb=new Databasehelper(this);
         items= new ArrayList<Expenses.ListViewItem>();


        //adapter= new MyAdapter(this, items);
        //l.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        items.clear();
        ListViewItem a= new ListViewItem();
        Cursor cur=mydb.getData();
        if(cur.getCount()==0)
            Toast.makeText(this, "No expenses to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        cur.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            a.category=cur.getString(0);
            a.status=cur.getString(1);
            a.amount=cur.getString(2);
            items.add(a);
        }while(cur.moveToNext());
        adapter= new MyAdapter(this, items);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);
        for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(items.get(i).category+" "+items.get(i).status+" "+items.get(i).amount);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.expenses, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class ListViewItem{
        public String category, amount, status;
    }

    public void onAdd(View v){
        Intent in= new Intent(this, Input.class);
        startActivityForResult(in, 10);
    }

}
```

//please help populate the table.I suspect the resume method is at fault.When i //printed using the print command the list contains multiple copies of the same //row.However the table in the database contains correct tuples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Listview Adds The Same Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564986/android-listview-adds-the-same-item) and many, many others .... seems like you are too lazy to do some research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your do while loop. When you are iterating through a cursor, you are using the same ListViewItem object to set values. You should be creating a new ListViewItem object on every iteration of the cursor. Something like this:

```
    do {
        ListViewItem a = new ListViewItem()
        a.category=cur.getString(0);
        a.status=cur.getString(1);
        a.amount=cur.getString(2);
        items.add(a);
    } while(cur.moveToNext());
```

Comment: thanks a lot. That solved it. However, I did not understand what was happening previously. Wasn't 'a' getting overwritten and added to the list, in every iteration?

Comment: Nope, you were adding the same object to the list on every iteration. So all items in the listview were referencing a single object and hence were displaying the same data.