# populate widget with Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, widget, firebase-realtime-database

My app uses Firebase database and items are displayed correctly in a RecyclerView, but I want to display them also in a Widget. Since a widget is not an activity I run into all sort of problems using Firebase and ListView. Is there any way to populate a Widget from Firebase?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: sorry to say, no I haven't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005779/android-widget-list-view-showing-same-content-for-every-item/39099682 I believe this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Taking more than 20 seconds in onDataSetChanged() to fetch data from internet/Firebase Database will not display data on widget listview. 
You will have to use CountDownLatch.

Also, here is an example https://github.com/mvescovo/item-reaper

https://github.com/mvescovo/item-reaper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/michaelvescovo/android/itemreaper/widget/WidgetListService.java